# c++ count in for statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, atom-editor

I use atom when writing code in C++. When I auto complete a for statement it looks like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    /* code */
}
```

What does "count" mean (if anything)?

Comment: count = the number of items to display. For example if you are using a std::vector, count should be replaced with myvector.size()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is a variable, that should be defined 'before the loop', or like this:

```
int count = 10;
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

or just substitute count with a number i.e.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Count is a descriptive term identifying the number of iterations (of the loop).  Replace 'count' with a number or a symbol from which the iteration count can be computed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    /* code */
}
```

Here,

`for` - is as `for-loop`.

`size_t` is a type name.

`i` is a variable of `size_t` type.

`count` is a variable. This limits that till `i` is less then `count` the loop will continue.